# Erro no Wordpress no painel Administrativo

Tags: sql, wordpress

Pessoal desenvolvi um site com Wordpress que pode ser visto deste [link](http://site.iopem.com.br/) porem ao acessar o [wp-admin](http://site.iopem.com.br/wp-admin/) aparece esse erro o que pode ser:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Instalei um plugin de `quiz` estava mexendo normalmente e do nada apareceu esse erro

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho, primeiramente, desinstalar o plugin para a página voltar a rodar em produção.

Como está sem acesso ao painel administrativo, apague as pastas relacionadas ao plugin e em seguida, verifique se há rastros do plugin no seu banco de dados.

Verifique se tal plugin é compatível com sua versão do WP antes de reinstalá-lo.